# How to make indexing of a list faster?

Tags: python

I have a list of unsorted x,y,z and want to basically sort them in a correct way to easier get to what I want. I create an indexed list with the code below. The code works like it should and I get the indexed list. However it is slow and takes too long to do this. What are some ways I can make the function below run faster?

```py
def index_collision_list(obstacle_list):
    min_x = -40
    min_y = -40
    min_z = -2

    max_x = 40
    max_y = 40
    max_z = 20
    indexed_list = []
    indexed_list_append=indexed_list.append
    for ix in range((max_x - min_x) * 2):
        curr_list_x = []
        curr_list_x_append=curr_list_x.append
        for iy in range((max_y - min_y) * 2):
            curr_list_y = []
            curr_list_y_append=curr_list_y.append
            for iz in range((max_z - min_z) * 2):
                curr_list_z = []
                curr_list_y_append(curr_list_z)
            curr_list_x_append(curr_list_y)
        indexed_list_append(curr_list_x)

    for i in range(len(obstacle_list)):
        curr_x = obstacle_list[i].x
        curr_y = obstacle_list[i].y
        curr_z = obstacle_list[i].z
        rounded_x = round_of_rating(curr_x, min_x)
        rounded_y = round_of_rating(curr_y, min_y)
        rounded_z = round_of_rating(curr_z, min_z)

        indexed_list[rounded_x][rounded_y][rounded_z].append(obstacle_list[i])

    return indexed_list


def round_of_rating(number, min_val):
    round_num = round(number * 2) / 2
    round_num = int((round_num - min_val) * 2)

    return round_num
```

Comment: Add the definition of `round_of_rating` too, please.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your desired output. It is impossible to reproduce when many items are ambiguous

Comment: Why you put the `append` in a variable?

Comment: @dome It's a micro-optimization that avoids an attribute lookup.

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to _achieve_ - `indexed_list` looks like a less useful data structure than the original `obstacle_list` for a lot of applications. Maybe what you actually want is an oct-tree

Comment: Added round of rating now, but it's just a rounding function.

Comment: What I want is to be able to have a structured list so that I can look up where I need to instead of having to look through all of the unsorted obstacle_list. The items in obstacle_list are x,y,z coordinates but unsorted. What I basically do is to sort them so I can find the ones near a specific point.

Comment: Mm, "sorting" has the specific meaning of ordering a list of items into a specific order – this is more like bucketing (or binning), i.e. grouping items into several categories or collections with a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing (80 * 2) * (80 * 2) * (22 * 2) = 1,126,400 lists to begin with, maybe just use a dictionary indexed with a 3-tuple?

This should be much more performant especially if the result cells will be sparse (i.e. if you don't expect all cells to have `obstacle`s in them).

The ever-handy `collections.defaultdict` makes this quite elegant:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def round_of_rating(number, min_val):
    round_num = round(number * 2) / 2
    round_num = int((round_num - min_val) * 2)
    return round_num


def index_collision_list(obstacle_list):
    min_x = -40
    min_y = -40
    min_z = -2    
    by_rounded_coords = defaultdict(list)

    for obstacle in obstacle_list:
        rounded_x = round_of_rating(obstacle.x, min_x)
        rounded_y = round_of_rating(obstacle.y, min_y)
        rounded_z = round_of_rating(obstacle.z, min_z)
        by_rounded_coords[rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z].append(obstacle)

    return by_rounded_coords
```

If this is still not fast enough, you should maybe consider an octree, as mentioned by @SpoonMeiser in the comments.

*EDIT:* The defaultdict-backed implementation is *very* much faster than the original with small obstacle counts (when uniformly distributed into the space) and approaches the speed (or lack thereof) of the original implementation, as expected, when there are more of them, but seems never slower than the original. Note both axes are logarithmic. The Y axis is seconds taken per 5 executions of both functions.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could sort list much faster using inbuilt method sort() with key parameter
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-sort/

```
def sort_func():
    #your func

your_list.sort(key=sort_func)
```